# How to get files from Adobe Draw CC on Ipad into Adobe Illustrator CC on PC as vector file

Tags: vector, file-format, ipad, adobe-draw

As the title says.

I have designed a sticker on Adobe Draw CC and I need to upload it to a website as CMYK, 300 DPI, and a specific size in inches.
In order to save the file I need to transfer it to the PC first since the Adobe Draw CC doesn't allow you to select specifics to save a file.
I can "send to adobe illustrator" or "send to adobe photoshop" as options on the Ipad but it seems it is not a vector file when sent.

Any ideas?

Comment: Save it to CC library in Draw and in Illustrator, open `Window > Libraries` and it should be there.

Comment: Joonas unfortunately that saves it as a png file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution:

1. Make sure you are logged into the same current Creative Cloud account on both the Ipad and the PC.
2. On the Ipad choose "Send to Adobe Illustrator CC"
3. It does not matter if Adobe Illustrator is open or not, it will auto open with the file that you sent over.
4. This new file with be in .ai file type with all the layers you have created